# How do I interpret the results of this glmer function?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I'm working on building my understanding of generalised linear mixed-effects models in R.

I have a toy dataset which is an RCT of treatment with aspirin that followed up people over time to track their outcomes, including death. The intervention was clustered by city in this dataset.

My current code is:

```
# Import libraries.

library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

# Apply model.

lme4::glmer(
  Death ~ Aspirin_Use + (1 | City),
  data = df_aspirin,
  family = poisson(link = "log"),
  offset = log(Length_In_Study),
)
```

The results I get are below using the dummy dataframe at the end of this question:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: Death ~ Aspirin_Use + (1 | City)
   Data: df_aspirin
 Offset: log(Length_In_Study)
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 22.0010  26.2046  -8.0005  16.0010       27 
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Std.Dev.
 City   (Intercept) 5.716   
Number of obs: 30, groups:  City, 29
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  Aspirin_Use  
   -13.9151      -0.8896
```

How do I interpret the intercept and aspirin_use results under the fixed effects section?

And I've seen other examples that include z-scores, p-values in the results and so on ... why aren't they shown here? Is it to do with the type of model applied?

I'm working through this stats area quickly so apologies if I'm missing fundamental concepts.

My df_aspirin data:

```
structure(list(City = structure(c("449", "563", "049", "006", 
"520", "171", "463", "599", "012", "462", "230", "218", "591", 
"130", "148", "557", "246", "491", "444", "563", "107", "247", 
"487", "214", "198", "549", "191", "227", "428", "257"), label = "City of Residence"), 
    Aspirin_Use = structure(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), label = "Intervention or Control -- Intervention is 1"), 
    Death = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "All deaths: number of events per participant"), 
    Length_In_Study = structure(c(1047, 1951, 572, 1853, 1968, 
    1872, 2011, 1948, 1853, 852, 1874, 1874, 1357, 1871, 1871, 
    737, 1862, 1965, 1781, 1951, 1862, 1862, 1965, 1875, 1874, 
    1467, 1874, 1874, 2011, 1858), label = "Duration in study (days)")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Use `summary` on the model object instead of only printing it.

Comment: you can check it here https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/intercept-in-fixed-effects-model/